# Safe access to parent class by casting first field

Tags: c++, gcc

I've been using the pattern below to bind data with arbitrary objects. Every `T` object lives in a `Wrapper<T>`, with the extra data accessible at a fixed offset from `T`'s own address.

```
template <class T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T core;
    int id;

    template <class ...Args>
    Wrapper(int id, Args&&... args)
        : id(id)
        , core(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
};

template <class T>
Wrapper<T>& getWrapper(T& core)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Wrapper<T>&>(core);
}

void process(std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << "'" << s << "' - id "
        << getWrapper(s).id << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto *wrapper = new Wrapper<std::string>(188, "Costa Rica");

    process(wrapper->core);
}
```

If my understanding of the standard is correct, this is portable provided `T` has standard-layout.

My question is GCC specific. Per GCC object model, can I assume this will work also when `T` is not standard-layout?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you suspected, the answer is that no you can't. The trick with [standard-layout classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) is that they can be safely casted with `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer to their first non-static data member and back again. You are doing this in your `getWrapper()` method.

A standard-layout class becomes non-standard the moment it gains any virtual members or uses virtual inheritance. When this happens gcc places the vtable pointer at offset zero so you can no longer do the `reinterpret_cast` to the first data member.

In your implementation you might consider using `std::is_standard_layout` to guard against incorrect usage of your pattern.

Comment: Even if T has a vtable, why would this affect the reinterpret_cast? What matters is the Wrapper having "standard" layout (no vtable), regardless of T layout. Note, I also assume T's address coincides with its vtable pointer.